# Resize CiViCRM image in Drupal views

Tags: drupal-7, civicrm

How to resize civicrm images(uploaded via webform) in Drupal views.
The images are getting displayed but the width and height are of the size when they upload images..

Answer (score 2):

2 solutions come to mind

1. Use css to give each image a `max-width` property. This will make images appear correctly, but won't save bandwidth as the full image will be downloaded and scaled client-side.
2. Use a drupal module such as [Image Resize Filter](https://drupal.org/project/image_resize_filter)

Answer (score 1):

If you need more advanced resizing / image transformation options, you can create a custom template file for the image URL field and use drupal image style (admin/config/media/image-styles) to define the required conversion.

As CiviCRM is protecting the files (we don't have the files urls in the database since 4.4.4 ?), you need to use imagecache_external (didn't manage to make [image_style_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7) work). The drawback of this module is that the image is duplicated in drupal.

Anyway, to make this work :

- install imagecache_external, go to the configuration page (`http://YOUR_SITE/admin/config/media/imagecache_external`) and add YOUR_SITE to the white list
- create a style `http://YOUR_SITE/admin/config/media/image-styles/add`
- configure the view as needed and add the CiviCRM Image URL field
- Edit the view -> Advanced -> Information
- Find the file name corresponding to the field you want to customize and create the file with this file name in `YOUR_THEME/templates/`
- Paste the following code (replace `'thumbnail'` with the style name you have created) :

  ```
  <?php
  if ($row->{$field->field_alias} != '') {
    print theme('imagecache_external', array(
      'path' => $row->{$field->field_alias},
      'style_name'=> 'thumbnail'));
  }
  ?>
  ```
- back to Edit the view -> Advanced -> Information -> Rescan templates file and then save the view.

Comment: This didn't quite work - see my answer below for template changes

Answer (score 0):

This didn't quite work on a drupal 7 / CiviCRM 5.10+ system (don't know if it still works on earlier).
To make it work put this in the template file:

```
<?php
$path = $field->render($row);
if (!empty($path)) {
  print theme('imagecache_external', array(
    'path' => $path,
    'style_name'=> 'thumbnail'));
}
?>
```